# Can I get a list of people who have received letters with a specific content?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I want to get all users who sent messages through my application.

- Is there a list of users who sent these messages?
- Does the privacy policy allow me to get this list?

Answer (score 0):

Read the privacy policy for point 2, that's all anyone here would do http://developers.facebook.com/policy/ as for point 1, IF you are allowed i think you might need to store this yourself when you send the message via your app which shouldn't be a big job. The api should return you an Id if the message was created successfully So you can either store that or just update a count field in your database. I don't think there is a way to just get the count from the api (especially one specific to your app)